# Return parent ID if all children referencing the parent ID have selected value

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I have run into a bit of a weird case at work.  I need to determine all items within a table that reference their parent and of those which ones have a certain value. For example

```
id  | parentID | fieldValue
---------------------------
123    null      null
  124    123       2
  125    123       2
126    null      null
  127    126       2
  128    126       1
```

Given the above example, if my subselect were to be searching for all children with a fieldValue of "2", I would only want the ID of 123 returned, as 126 has a child with a 1 value.

The goal is that:

HasParentID not null, if field value of ALL OTHER children = 2, return parentID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group by parentID` and set the conditions in the `having` clause:

```
select parentID
from tablename
group by parentID
having count(distinct fieldValue) = 1 and max(fieldValue) = '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` clause to check that a `parentID` has no children with a `fieldValue` other than `2`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parentID
FROM data d1
WHERE d1.fieldValue = 2
  AND d1.parentID IS NOT NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM data d2
                  WHERE d2.parentID = d1.parentID AND d2.fieldValue != 2)
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b5c92/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT parentID 
  FROM data
  WHERE fieldValue = 2
    AND parentID NOT IN 
      (SELECT parentId 
       FROM data
       WHERE fieldValue != 2)
```